# Pass null arguments to native module in React-Native android

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react-native NativeModule with a single method

```
@ReactMethod
public void sendEvent(String message, Integer code) {
  ...
}
```

I want to be able to pass `null` for the `code` argument in js, but when I do e.g.

```
TestModule.sendEvent('this is a test', null);
```

I get

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeArgumentsParseException: TypeError: expected dynamic type `double', but had type `null' (constructing arguments for TestModule.sendEvent at argument index 1)
```

How can `null` be passed as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass null in Integer values.

`public void sendEvent(String message, Integer code) {`

Here `Integer code` return invalid either pass `0` or change it to `String code`

So now you can pass null values.